# Why FIND returns nothing with structured table?

Tags: excel, vba, find, named-ranges, listobject

Hoping someone could shed something on my line of vba script below and point out the error:

```
Sub findKeyword()

Dim tbl as ListObject

set tbl = activesheet.ListOBjects("myTable") 'containing a header row

set r as range

set r = tbl.ListRows(1).Range.Find("name")

End sub
```

the Find keeps returning nothing when the header called name does exist in the header row of the structured table. On the other hand, set r = activesheet.rows(1).find("name") is able to find the search text.

Comment: `Set r = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Find("name")`

Comment: this is exactly what i needed indeed! thanks

Comment: `Debug.Print tbl.ListRows(1).Range.Address` will clarify it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListRows` = all the rows of **data** in the ListObject.

It's not the range with the headers.

`tbl.Listcolumns("name")`

will give you a reference to the "name" column.